# Pode-se fazer o navegador "lembrar" de uma senha programaticamente?

Tags: javascript, autenticação, segurança, senhas

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde a partir de uma senha fornecida pelo usuário um par de chaves (autenticação e criptografia) é derivado. A senha em si nunca é enviada ao servidor, somente a chave de autenticação*.

Gostaria de oferecer ao usuário a opção do navegador "lembrar" sua senha**. É possível fazer isso, via JavaScript, e de forma segura?

Li diversas referências (por exemplo, [essa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2382329/520779)) e pelo jeito não há um meio consistente entre os diversos browsers (ex.: o Chrome só oferece para salvar a senha no **retorno** da submissão do formulário, e só se **a própria senha** tiver sido submetida - o que não é o caso aqui, pois a senha não deve nunca sair do browser). Estou procurando por alternativas.

1. É possível "forçar" o browser a salvar um campo `password` arbitrário, com o mesmo nível de segurança que ele salvaria uma senha submetida? (ainda que essa segurança [não seja assim tão elevada...](https://superuser.com/a/416277/166021)) De preferência, satisfazendo essa restrição adicional de não enviá-la ao servidor.
2. Se não dá para salvar junto com as senhas, haveria uma solução "igualmente boa"? Considerei por exemplo a opção de usar `localStorage`, apesar dos [avisos enfáticos](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Storage_APIs) que "não se deve armazenar informações confidenciais no `localStorage`". Entretanto, não vejo como usá-lo possa ser pior do que salvar a senha no browser - uma vez que alguém com acesso local ao computador também poderá ler essas senhas... A única desvantagem que vejo é que ele é mais vulnerável a XSS - o que acredito não ser necessariamente o caso com as senhas salvas do jeito "normal", sem envolver JavaScript (ou estou enganado?).

   - Nota: conheço a [**WebCrypto API**](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) sendo desenvolvida. No futuro - quando a mesma estiver consolidada e amplamente suportada - ela pode vir a se tornar a solução ideal. Entretanto, estou analisando alternativas a curto prazo.

---

* **e não a de criptografia:** toda a criptografia ocorre no lado cliente, de modo que nem o servidor tem acesso aos dados do usuário; por essa razão, a senha original deve ser mantida confidencial **inclusive** do servidor. Mais detalhes [do meu caso particular] [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/37487/6939).

** Assuma como **premissa** que o usuário optou por armazenar a senha. Tenho consciência que esse é um *tradeoff* segurança vs. conveniência, e gostaria de oferecer ao usuário diferentes **opções** a respeito - em vez de **impor** isso a ele. Uma discussão aprofundada sobre segurança seria *off-topic* aqui (mais apropriada para [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) por exemplo), essa pergunta refere-se somente a um problema de **programação**: comandar o browser para salvar uma senha através dos seus mecanismos usuais.

---

**Atualização:** por "exigência popular", aqui vai o meu *threat model* ("modelo de ameaças") e outros requisitos particulares.

1. A principal preocupação é **confidencialidade na nuvem**; ou seja, ainda que o **código** da minha aplicação (JavaScript) tenha de vir necessariamente de uma fonte confiável (caso contrário, nada do que eu fizesse iria garantir a segurança), o servidor onde os dados são **armazenados** é "menos-que-confiável" (i.e. há o interesse de se "esconder" a infomação confidencial mesmo dele - ainda que não se presuma malícia *a priori*).
2. A resistência contra acesso local não autorizado **não é** uma preocupação; assume-se que qualquer um com acesso físico à máquina está autorizado a acessar esses dados (e se, pra um usuário particular, isso não for verdadeiro, ele será instruído a **não salvar** sua senha dessa maneira).
3. A **facilidade de uso** é um requisito de extrema importância; instalar plugins (Java, WebPG, etc), gerenciadores de senha (LastPass, KeePass, etc), usar um *browser* ou SO particular (muitos tem integração nativa com "chaveiros" seguros) ou mesmo um servidor *proxy* local poderão ser oferecidos como **opção** para os indivíduos mais conscientes em segurança, mas não devem ser **obrigatórios**: o sistema deve ser usável somente com os recursos nativos do navegador, independente de plataforma.

Estou postando isso aqui porque tenho recebido demasiadas sugestões de "não fazer isso" ou "fazer aquilo em vez disso", mas minha pergunta original não é sobre segurança, e sim **programação**: se é ou não possível usar o mecanismo nativo do *browser* de "lembrar as senhas" (cada um tem um, mas a funcionalidade é equivalente) **programaticamente**.

Comment: Por que não usar SSL? 
http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Comment: @hernandes Dar a **opção** do usuário usar certificados no lado cliente pode ser uma boa ideia, mas não pretendo tornar isso mandatório. Preferiria que o acesso fosse possível somente com algo que o usuário **sabe** (i.e. ele não precise estar de **posse** de algo - no caso o arquivo do certificado - para acessar o sistema).

Comment: Acesso via HTTPS não necessita de certificado no *client*. Desde que a senha não seja enviada num parâmetro `GET`, qual seria a preocupação com a segurança da informação transmitida?

Comment: @utluiz (não sei se seu comentário é dirigido a mim ou ao hernandes, mas vou responder) Minha pergunta não é sobre a segurança da **comunicação** - ela vai usar SSL/TSL, e a chave de autenticação será passada via `POST` - mas sim sobre a segurança de **dados armazenados no browser**. Se o usuário **optar** pelo browser lembrar sua senha (a propósito, a pergunta também **não é** sobre "lembrar a sessão") ele assume os riscos que isso acarreta (i.e. quem tem acesso local à máquina poderia recuperar essa senha). E certificados no client são uma boa **alternativa**, mas a pergunta é sobre senhas.

Comment: Não seria possível utilizar os cookies para armazenar o valor da senha (caso seja um problema armazenar a senha em plaintext, cifrá-la para salvar e decifrá-la quando recebé-la dos cookies) e carregar a senha no `onload` da página?

Comment: @felipe.avelar E com que chave eu cifraria? O problema é que, se eu tivesse um meio seguro de armazenar uma chave dessas, eu poderia simplesmente usar esse meio para armazenar a própria senha... (sem ter que mexer com cookies)

Comment: Realmente, não havia pensado nisso, mas utilizando php, a chave poderia muito bem ficar do lado do servidor, não?
Pode ser uma sugestão equivocada, mas é uma forma (a única que eu consigo pensar agora) para resolver o seu problema.

Comment: @felipe.avelar O problema é que se a chave ficasse no servidor, **o servidor poderia decifrar a senha**. A razão de se usar criptografia no lado cliente é que nem o servidor tem acesso aos seus dados. (na pergunta, mencionei que duas chaves eram geradas, mas **somente a de autenticação** era enviada ao servidor; vou editar a pergunta dar mais ênfase a esse fato)

Comment: Huuum, tendi, bem não sei se é uma solução possível pra você, mas um sistema [passwordless](http://blog.jmac.org/blog/2013/10/13/thinking-about-passwordless-web-logins/) não seria o ideal, nesse caso?
Ainda é possível ver mais informações [aqui](http://notes.xoxco.com/post/27999787765/is-it-time-for-password-less-login) e [aqui](http://activedoc.opensuse.org/what-is-a-passwordless-login).

Comment: @felipe.avelar De fato, não é uma solução possível pra mim, mas é uma técnica interessante - que eu ainda não conhecia - e pode me servir bem em outros contextos. Neste não serve, pois ainda é necessário manter offline a chave de criptografia... i.e. o servidor não a conhece, então não pode incluir no link enviado por e-mail; e de qualquer forma, essa solução assume que o provedor de e-mail é **confiável** (o que na prática, é uma premissa frequente). Muitas vezes isso é "bom o bastante", mas no meu caso não pretendo usar o e-mail como *fallback* (seja de autenticação ou de criptografia).

Comment: @downvoter Se há algo de errado nessa pergunta, favor deixar um comentário para que a mesma possa ser aprimorada...

Comment: @mgibsonbr, uma coisa bastante importante (fundamental?) quando pensamos em "segurança", e que eu estou sentindo falta na pergunta (e na discussão nos comentários), é uma definição clara do "threat model". A definição do threat model permite tanto a você quanto às pessoas que tentarão responder à sua questão entenderem melhor quais os seus "medos", quais os vetores de ataque dos quais você quer se proteger, etc. Ex: o seu sistema deve ser resistente a *eavesdropping*? E *MITM*? E *XSS*? E acesso local? E a extensions? Sem as respostas, é difícil propor uma boa solução.

Comment: @BrunoReis Quando fiz essa pergunta aqui, quis manter o escopo limitado a uma simples pergunta de programação, bem objetiva. Tudo isso que você falou é importante, mas eu optaria por ter essa discussão no [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) em vez de aqui. Não que a pergunta - se bem formulada - não esteja *on-topic* nesse site (ele é um pouquinho mais amplo que o SO em inglês), mas o foco desse site é outro, e os "especialistas" que ele atrai são outros. Reconheço que fui um pouco infeliz quando pedi por alternativas, deveria ter limitado ao comportamento padrão do browser, só.

Comment: Quero reforçar algo importante para avaliar esta pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com

Comment: @mgibsonbr Será que essa thread do SO(en) te ajuda? Já deu uma olhada lá? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password

Comment: @LuizVieira Valeu pela sugestão, mas eu próprio já tinha postado esse link na pergunta: "Li diversas referências (por exemplo, essa pergunta no SOEN) ..."

Comment: @mgibsonbr Oops. Foi mals. :)

Comment: ainda vou responder essa pergunta.... kkkk @mgibsonbr

Answer (score 9):

Eu desenvolvi há um tempo uma solução prática, que está em uso, que consiste no seguinte:

1. O usuário estando logado tem acesso a um bookmarklet com token único
2. Ele pode arrastar esse bookmarklet pra barra de links ou para os bookmarks normalmente
3. Ao clicar nesse bookmarklet, ele guarda o token na propriedade window.name e carrega uma determinada URL
4. Esta URL contém um JS também com token único
5. O JS mescla os 2 tokens e faz o *hash*
6. O usuário é redirecionado para outra URL com o *hash* como parâmetro

Notar que o token do bookmarklet nunca trafega em aberto, apenas o *hash* resultante.

Como o servidor tem o *hash* dos bookmarklets do usuário, basta revogar no painel de controle os tokens pré existentes se houver desconfiança de mau uso, caso se queira obrigar o usuário a reinstalar um bookmarklet atualizado.

Comment: Nunca tinha pensado nisso, guardar uma informação confidencial na barra de favoritos... Pesquisei um pouco sobre isso, e me parece que é seguro contra XSS (os favoritos são inacessíveis para o código JavaScript). Não gostaria de estimular os usuários a usarem bookmarklets, pois eles são inerentemente inseguros, mas esse seria um caso em que um bom uso dos mesmos pode aprimorar a segurança de um sistema. Vou avaliar com cuidado essa sugestão (talvez abra uma pergunta no [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com))

Comment: Desenvolvi isso justamente para uma situação em que o acesso ao aplicativo teria que ser bem fácil, pois o login constante seria um desestímulo muito grande pro uso regular do mesmo, visto a necessidade de se anotar e recuperar rapidamente informações no sistema. Tentei várias outras coisas e nada agradou, e como teria que ser multi-browser, essa foi a saida mais interessante. Tem uma pequena restrição no IE, quanto a arrastar bookmarklets, mas é "contornavel". Nos outros browsers testados funcionou bem (FF,Opera,Chrome/Iron).

Comment: Fiquei realmente interessado nessa ideia, e acabei postando [uma pergunta no security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/49517/6939). Vamos ver o que respondem. Mas já adiantando: você lembrou de **limpar** o `window.name` depois que o hash foi computado? Isso é importante, caso contrário ele corre o risco de ficar exposto caso o usuário utilize o **botão voltar** do navegador... (e de fato [existem ataques que exploram essa possibilidade](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/switch/))

Comment: De qualquer forma não adiantaria muito, pois o window.name sozinho não é suficiente para logar, tem o hash do servidor que é único por login, e não seria possível reutilizar. Mas é limpo sim, para evitar que uma URL de terceiro tenha acesso a isso (mas só como curiosidade, você deve imaginar como seria improvável alguém conseguir fazer a pessoa reaproveitar justo aquela janela numa URL "contaminada" né :) )

Comment: Hehe você chegou a experimentar o link no meu último comentário? Talvez precisasse de alguma "engenharia social", sim, mas não acho tão improvável que o atacante conseguisse fazer a vítima abrir o site numa aba **aparentemente** vazia, mas que na verdade **o atacante controla**. (mas isso de combinar o token salvo com um token único do servidor me parece uma defesa apropriada)

Answer (score 1):

Tudo que for armazenado no browser poderá ser alvo de um XSS, de alguma forma. E cada browser terá o seu próprio método de armazenar campos (como o da senha ou chave de criptografia), o que torna dificil uma solução universal.

Você poderia então utilizar um pequeno programa em [JNLP / Java web start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start). Desta forma, o usuário estaria rodando um programa na sua máquina, sem ter contato com o servidor, mas sem as dificuldades de instalar o programa, etc. Se você assinar o programa ou mostrar ao usuário como configurar corretamente os níveis de acesso, esta "senha" da criptografia simétrica poderia ser armazenada no computador local do usuário, inclusive criptografada com alguma outra chave que o seu programa java utilizará.

Comment: "Tudo que for armazenado no browser poderá ser alvo de um XSS, de alguma forma" não que isso resolva meu caso, mas um cookie `HTTP-ONLY` não poderia ser capturado via JavaScript, não? De todo modo, gostei da sua sugestão, não responde diretamente à pergunta (preferiria algo que fosse nativamente suportado pelo browser) mas é uma ideia interessante a se considerar - desenvolver um "módulo de segurança" para a minha aplicação.

Comment: @mgibsonbr conseguiu uma solução?

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho que a melhor solução para isso é **não fazer**. É só ler o título uma vez para saber que isso tende a dar errado. No momento que você que conseguir pensar em algo, implementar e colocar no ar, quando alguém que é "atacante" perceber que existe essa funcionalidade no seu sistema, e que não é gravado no browser, ele vai ficar muito curioso, vai estudar e tentar entender o que você fez. Ele vai descobrir, sempre descobrem. Segurança por obscuridade não é o melhor caminho.

E agora vamos pensar pelo lado do usuário, o que isso trás de bom para ele? Deixa eu pensar... já sei! Ele vai clicar em login e vai logar. Facilidade é uma coisa legal. Só que isso se torna uma comodidade, e logo, logo ele vai esquecer a senha. E se em algum momento ele precisar usar a senha, o que vai acontecer? Reset de senha. Um longo caminho de facilidades, para chegar em um reset de senha. Isso acontece em bancos, eles usam outros meios de acesso a sua conta(impressão digital, letras), e no momento que você precisa da senha, você não lembra. E por quê? Porque você não usa.

Acho melhor você parar e pensar se realmente isso é uma coisa boa.

Comment: 1) Meu projeto é *open source*, qualquer um pode ver os fontes... "Segurança por obscuridade" seria se eu tentasse esconder o **algoritmo**. Mas um algoritmo pode ser **público** e ainda assim **seguro** (o que tem que ser secreto é a chave). 2) Um usuário típico possui dezenas de contas em serviços diferentes. Ele cria uma senha distinta, e forte, em cada um deles? Não, ele **reusa** a senha ou **anota em algum lugar**. Se eu oferecer um meio minimamente seguro dele armazenar a senha, apesar de todos os pesares já é um avanço. E ele não vai ter que resetar nunca - pois a senha está lá, salva.

Comment: P.S. Não estou dizendo que salvar senhas é sempre uma coisa boa. Não é, e usuários mais conscientes não vão fazer isso. Mas pela minha experiência - corroborada pela opinião da maioria dos especialistas em segurança - não adianta tentar "forçar" o usuário a adotar um comportamento inconveniente em nome da segurança. Chega um ponto em que os usuários começam a ativamente "lutar contra o sistema". Em outras palavras, "segurança só funciona se for fácil"...

Answer (score -1):

A sua principal dúvida é onde armazenar?

Com a segurança que você quer implementar, seria interessante armazenar?

Vamos por partes.

Armazenamento que temos hoje nos browsers são todos passíveis de XSS. A unica possibilidade que eu vejo seria mesmo uma aplicação JAWS (como woliveirajr disse), mas mesmo essa aplicação será que conseguiria manter o armazenamento intacto?

Para a solução que você está montando eu acredito que retirar a opção de "armazenar" seria a mais interessante, forçar o usuário a sempre logar. Imagina um banco ou um homebroker usando essa tecnologia, deixando a responsabilidade do armazenamento da "senha" na maquina  do usuário.

Comment: Infelizmente, "forçar o usuário a sempre logar" pode ser o mesmo que "fazer os usuários não usarem mais o meu sistema"... Estou pensando em algo mais "*low profile*" que bancos ou coisas assim (embora minha intenção é construir uma **plataforma**, não uma aplicação específica, de modo que não está em meu controle como exatamente ela será usada). Reitero o que disse no comentário à resposta do Jodson Leandro, "segurança só funciona se for fácil". E dependendo do *threat model*, acesso local no computador do cliente pode não ser uma preocupação, mas confidencialidade na nuvem sim.

Comment: Talvez você possa usar o cookie [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) setando uma chave que será recuperada validando junto com a chave recebida do JS.

Comment: Ih, um cookie HttpOnly é basicamente **o contrário** do que eu estou procurando: uma coisa que o servidor vê, mas o JavaScript não vê... (o que eu quero é algo que o JavaScript vê mas o servidor não vê) HttpOnly é muito bom para "lembrar a sessão", mas não tanto para "lembrar a senha".

Answer (score -1):

Simples.

Antigamente guardava-se este tipo de info em cookies mas agora com as novas versões html5 de browser pode-se guardar tudo usando LOCAL STORAGE.

Da mesma maneira que o site de bitcoin blockchain guarda tudo encriptado no proprio browser do user, assim nada fica guardado server side.

Atenção este site http://blockchain.info é o mais usado como wallet de bitcoin e responsavel por centenas e centenas de milhares de euros em bitcoins de quase 1 milhao de utilizadores.

Tudo feito com localStorage... ACHO QUE PODES CONFIAR :)

Mais info como usar local storage:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Valeu pela sugestão, mas como eu citei na pergunta, [os avisos da OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Storage_APIs) sobre o local storage me deixaram com a pulga atrás da orelha... Aliás, o blockchain.info [**não armazena** senhas no local storage](https://blockchain.info/pt/wallet/security): "No sensitive data is stored in your browser's local storage. If available the site will cache your wallet identifier, address balances and transactions, in the event of login with a different identifier this data is cleared."

Comment: Sim realmente a password em si nao guarda.

Apenas guarda o identifier e outros dados..

Da para consultar na console do chrome.

O que podes guardar é uma versão encriptada da pass que é enviado para o server e com o php decriptas a pass, se for a mesma autoriza a session.

Ou então é usar the old cookie system.

Comment: Salvar "uma versão encriptada" da senha é equivalente a salvar a senha em *plaintext*: pois se o server é que vai decifrar, então o *ciphertext* **é a credencial** - não importa se nós chamamos isso de "senha" ou de outra coisa (ex.: se um atacante tem aceso ao CT, ele simplesmente manda pro servidor e está autenticado). Ou seja, não estou dizendo que cifrar "piora as coisas", simplesmente que a cifra é redundante (usar ou não usar não faz diferença, se for feito desse jeito).