# Como programas armazenam senhas salvas?

Tags: segurança, aplicação-web

Na internet é comum ter o "lembrar senha" nos campos de login.Sei que este é feito pelos desenvolvedores da aplicação, mas como o google chrome,por exemplo, armazena uma senha salva? Já que a maioria das aplicações não foi desenvolvida para ter uma integração do gênero com o navegador(pelo menos que eu saiba).

Ele simplesmente guarda um "plain text" da senha?

Comment: Que eu saiba, [no browser] é automático, inclusive há um tempo abri [uma outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/215) para saber se seria possível o programador ter mais influência sobre o processo. Quando ao modo de armazenar, não é "plain text", mas só para prevenir acesso acidental - seja qual for o processo usado (criptografia, provavelmente) é um processo reversível e muito provavelmente acessível a qualquer administrador do SO ou pessoa com acesso físico à máquina.

Comment: P.S. No caso do Google Chrome, é bastante fácil acessar as senhas salvas, como indicado por [essa postagem](http://www.engadget.com/2013/08/07/chrome-saved-passwords/) (em inglês): basta abrir o endereço `chrome://settings/passwords` clicar na senha que quer exibir e no botão "Mostrar"...

Answer (score 1):

Quando a autenticação a um sistema externo é feita por senha, essa senha corresponde à **credencial de acesso** a esse sistema - ou seja, para se autenticar com ele, você precisa apresentar essa senha, no seu formato original. Por essa razão, seja qual for o meio que o programa utilize para armazenar essa senha, esse processo precisa necessariamente ser **reversível** (i.e. tem de ser possível obter a senha original a partir do que quer que tenha sido armazenado no disco).

O problema é: como proteger essa senha? Você não pode hasheá-la, pois os hashes não são reversíveis. Você poderia cifrá-la, mas onde guardar a chave? Se a chave estiver num arquivo logo ao lado da senha cifrada, isso é o mesmo que trancar sua porta e deixar a chave na fechadura... Você poderia também guardar essa chave num armazenamento externo, e pedir que o usuário o inserisse toda vez que ele quisesse usar a senha salva, mas aí qual a vantagem de memorizar a senha? Guarda **ela** no dispositivo externo de uma vez... Da mesma forma, se você cifrar a senha salva com outra senha, você evita de ter que digitar uma senha mas passa a ter que digitar outra, então qual a vantagem?...

(Falo do ponto de vista do usuário, é claro - pode-se sim ter vantagens em se usar uma "senha mestra" que desbloqueie o acesso a todas as suas senhas salvas. O Firefox, por exemplo, [oferece essa opção](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/kb/use-uma-senha-mestra-para-proteger-logins-e-senhas). Ou você pode usar um [gerenciador de senhas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerenciador_de_senha), com integração ao browser. Mas em geral só aqueles mais preocupados com segurança fazem isso, o usuário comum só quer não ter que digitar a senha e pronto!)

Por conta disso, a maioria dos programas que armazena senhas de outros serviços (e nesse caso, ajuda a discussão não se referir a elas como "senhas", mas sim como ["segredos"](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/53045/6939)) não toma nenhuma medida extrema para protegê-las: ou guarda em texto plano mesmo, ou coloca num arquivo binário e/ou usa uma ofuscação simples para prevenir acessos **acidentais** (não se preocupando com acessos maliciosos), ou delega essa tarefa a outro sistema - por exemplo o sistema operacional. Não existe uma forma padronizada de se fazer isso, justamente porque não existe uma resposta "certa" - de qualquer jeito que você fizer, a pessoa que está sentada na frente do browser e que tem a opção de *usar* a senha salva por definição tem acesso irrestrito a ela (nem que seja abrindo o console do navegador e inspecionando o que foi enviado no `POST`...).

Answer (score 0):

Os sites usam cookies que é um arquivo de texto que tem como principal função armazenar as preferências do usuário em todos os sites. Quando você busca algum produto em determinado site e ele aparece em sua tela quando você navega em outras páginas, foi o cookie quem informou isso ao sistema. É o cookie quem diz que você é você e que você queria aquele produto.

No caso de senhas os navegadores usam a memoria cache é um armazenamento temporário no disco rígido de páginas web, imagens e outros documentos e ficheiros utilizando técnicas de cache para reduzir o uso largura de banda disponível, aumentar a velocidade do acesso, entre outras vantagens.

Baseado nesse conceito, os navegadores, ao acessarem um site, guardam uma cópia dos arquivos usados pelo mesmo no disco rígido; ela pode ser usada na montagem da página ao invés de trafegar todo o arquivo original pela Internet inteira até o seu computador novamente.

Você pode baixar a ferramenta ChromePass. É gratuita que exibe senhas salvas no navegador Google Chrome. A melhor coisa sobre esta ferramenta gratuita é mesmo permite exportar essas senhas em um arquivo no formato HTML, XML.